# Packages ucs and hyperref don't get along under xelatex

Tags: xetex, hyperref, input-encodings, python

I'm getting an "undefined control sequence" error for `\UTFviii@loop` whenever I use both the `ucs` package and the `hyperref` package under XeLaTeX (and LuaLaTeX). (I understand `\UTFviii@loop` has something to do with input encodings.) An MWE is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\begin{document}
testing
\end{document}
```

which generates the following run:

```
% xelatex lab1-1.tex         
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./lab1-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)
(./lab1-1.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(./lab1-1.out) (./lab1-1.out)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyPsd@expand@utfvii ... {~{####1}}}\UTFviii@loop 
                                                  \count@ "E0 \@tempcnta "F0...
l.6 \end{document}
                  
?
```

This runs cleanly with PdfLaTeX:

```
% pdflatex lab1-1.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./lab1-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./lab1-1.aux) (./lab1-1.out) (./lab1-1.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def) [1{/usr/local/te
xlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./lab1-1.aux) )</usr
/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on lab1-1.pdf (1 page, 12687 bytes).
Transcript written on lab1-1.log.
%
```

I noted this problem only upon updating TeX Live to the current 2023 release. I had no problem under 2022.

**Some important context:** You might ask why I don't just use PdfLaTeX, or get rid of one or the other of the two packages (in particular, `ucs`). It's because the LaTeX code is generated by `nbconvert` and not by me. In particular, it was generated in the process of a Jupyter notebook conversion with `nbconvert --to pdf`, which generates the LaTeX code and uses XeLaTeX to process it. It is `nbconvert` that inserts the two packages. In fact, I generated the MWE by using `nbconvert --to latex` to generate the LaTeX code and then dropped bits until I was left with the MWE. You might wonder why I don't just use `nbconvert` to generate the LateX code and then separately use PdfLaTeX to get the PDF. That's because `nbconvert` inserts non-ASCII characters because it assumes that XeLaTeX will be used to process the LaTeX code.

Also, I'd just like to know what's going on.

Any help or insights greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ucs` is largely obsolete and definitely not compatible with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Doesn't `inputenc` do the same thing? (though that also doesn't work in XeLaTeX, from my experience)

Comment: well nbconvert shouldn't add ucs and it should certainly not add it if xelatex is used. That said ucs could probably add a test and bail out if an unicode engine is detected.

Comment: as @UlrikeFischer says we can probably avoid this in ucs but the package should not be loaded (in any engine) so that should be reported to nbconvert maintainers

Comment: @Someone `inputenc` works in xetex by outputting a warning that it should not be used, then doing nothing. Ulrike is suggesting `ucs` could do the same

Comment: I meant "same thing as `ucs` overall" when I said that. Both provide input encodings. Either way, `nbconvert` reeeally loves `ucs`, so I don't think I was going the right way with my idea.

Comment: I've been able to work around this problem by simply rolling back to TeX Live pre 2022. (Thankfully, TeX Live Utility makes it easy to pop between versions.) Why the problem doesn't appear until the 2022 version I do not know, but from the discussion above, this seems to be a problem for the ucs or nbconvert folks to look into. Thank you all for your help.